# Discrepancy between formatted numeric value and rounded value

Tags: python, numpy, rounding, number-formatting

I found this weird behavior using python and numpy:

```
print('%10.3f' %0.4975)
```

returns 0.497, while

```
numpy.round(0.4975,3)
```

returns 0.498 as expected.
With other similar numbers I always get the print statement to deliver the correctly rounded value (for example: 0.5975 --> 0.598).
Why is this?
I'm using python 3.4 and numpy 1.9.2 on windows 7.

Comment: It should have to do with the binary representation of floats in python and Numpy. Note that `.4975 - .497` results in `0.0005000000000000004` which is unequal to `0.0005`.

Comment: and to add to that, check the comments under 'round' in this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Thanks to @Dietrich and Dan Patterson. It really has to do with the way float numbers are represented. Bizarre but true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In double precision, 0.4975 is 8962163258467287/18014398509481984 which is slightly **less** than the real number 0.4975. Hence, Python's `round` function rounds it to 0.497.

In contrast, 0.5975 becomes 5381801554707743/9007199254740992 which is slightly **more** than the real number 0.5975. So we get the expected 0.598 when rounding.

Why does NumPy round 0.4975 to 0.498?  Its algorithm is a bit different: to round to N digits, it multiplies the given number by the Nth power of 10, rounds to nearest integer (preferring even), and then divides by 10^N. In the process of multiplication by powers of 10, the direction of truncation changes; often one will get exactly a half-integer as a result. (Example: 0.15*10 = 1.5 which is exactly 3/2, although 0.15 is not exactly 3/20).

Simply put, `np.round(x, 3)`  is the same as `round(x*1000)/1000`. You can check that both return 0.498 when applied to x = 0.4975. Indeed, in double precision 0.4975*1000 is *exactly* 497.5 (that is, 995/2), and the direction of rounding is then picked correctly.

Here is a comparison of how 0.05, 0.15, 0.25, ... are rounded:

#### Python

```
>>> [round((2*i+1)/20, 1) for i in range(10)] 
[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9]
```

#### NumPy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.around([(2*i+1)/20 for i in range(10)], 1)
array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.4,  0.6,  0.6,  0.8,  0.8,  1. ])
```

Here NumPy output is what one'd expect without thinking of binary representation.

However, `np.around([(2*i+1)/200 for i in range(100)], 2)` shows that NumPy's algorithm won't always match the expectation, either: there are two numbers (0.55 and 0.57) with an odd digit at the end. The problem is that, for example, 0.545*100 is not exactly 109/2; rather, it is 7670193115365377/140737488355328.